# Test Android RemoteControlClient without actual device

Tags: android, bluetooth, avrcp

Is there way to test app RemoteControlClient functionality without actual Bluetooth device that supports AVRCP 1.3 or higher profile?

Comment: AFAIK, a `RemoteControlClient` should work from an Android device lockscreen.

Comment: Lock screen shows only title and simple controls (play/pause and next/prev track). It does not show any other metadata, no current position.